# Can I use DeltaCopy & Volume Shadow Service to backup to another windows network server?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, backup, rsync

I'm wanting to replace our problematic backup server with an rsync based solution.
I've been looking at DeltaCopy which looks like it's a native version of rsync for windows.
Has anyone had experience of setting this up to backup their servers before?

Do I need a linux box to get this running? was looking at rsnapshot.  I have concerns around the file permissions between the different filesystems.

Thoughts and suggestions welcome.

EDIT: actually deltacopy is not native and uses cygwin.

Comment: Keep in mind that pretty much all windows rsync implementations currently have a 260 character path limit and does not support UTF-8.   You may have problems backing some files up. http://serverfault.com/questions/8880/

Comment: Thats disapointing.  I'm very tempted to create a native port without those limitations.  I'm suprised it doesn't already exist - rsync is a wonderful tool on unix systems.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync isn't going to get your ACLs, but you can use a separate too like [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10,loband%29.aspx) or [setacl](http://setacl.sourceforge.net/) to dump your ACLs out to a text file that you can use when you need to restore.

I am currently using [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) to pull a backup of non-critical systems.  It works ok.  I am pulling the backups to a Linux box using the [dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/) which is a perl script to do backups with rsync.

- None of the rsync solutions use the backup privilege.  This means they cannot bypass the filesystem acls, and your rsync service account must have at least read access to everything
- As i mentioned in the comment, until a rsync tool based on cygwin 1.7 is released you won't have support for files where the entire path is greater then 260 characters.
- You will have problems with files that have some unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks for that, dirvish looks great. Thanks for the heads up on the ACL's too.  Long filenames are something we may have an issue with though.  At least it looks feasible.